# JQuery validate plugin with e-mail validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, validation

I am currently using JQuery Validate plugin in along with some tip plugin to validate a form. I need to validate the e-mail address as well, other then just checking all fields have been filled out. I am familiar with the Validate `rules` function, however it causing a problem.

As soon as the e-mail evaluates to be invalid, with my current implementation, all following text fields appear to be invalid (by generating a plugin tip) and causes all following fields to have an annoying tip saying `this field is required` before the user even had a chance to fill them out.

I was wondering if there was a way to check if my e-mail validation function returned true from within the `validate` call, where if it does not return true, then consider the form invalid.

Later on I will need to implement a password regex function that will follow the same logic.

My Form Validation

```
 $(".form").validate({
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).css('border', '1px solid red');
                $('.addlefttip').qtip({
                    position: {
                        my: 'middle left', 
                        at: 'middle right'
                    },
                    show: {
                        event: 'focus'
                    },
                    hide:{
                       event: 'blur'
                    },
                    style: {
                            classes: 'qtip-blue qtip-shadow'
                        },
                        content: {
                            attr: 'alt'
                        },
                    });
                    $('.addtoptip').qtip({
                        position: {
                            my: 'bottom left', 
                            at: 'top right'
                        },
                        show: {
                            event: 'focus'
                        },
                        hide:{
                            event: 'blur'
                        },
                        style: {
                            classes: 'qtip-blue qtip-shadow'
                        },
                        content: {
                            attr: 'alt'
                        },
                    });
                },
                rules: {
                    email: {
                        minlength: 5
                    }
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).css('border', '1px solid #ddd');
                }
            });
```

My e-mail validation:

```
    $('.email-field').change(function(){
            var email = $(this).val();

            var re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

            if(re.test(email)) {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<span style="color:green; font-style:italic; font-weight:normal;"><img src="http://myhousesforsaleindetroit.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/green-check-mark.png"> valid';
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = '<img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/archive/8/89/20070603232424!RedX.png" style="width:15px; margin:-2px 0px 0px 0px;"/> invalid';
            }
        });
```

I appreciate any suggestions!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused due to me selecting `$('.addlefttip').qtip({...` within the highlight definition. Changing the selector to `element` fixed the problem described.

```
 highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).css('border', '1px solid red');
                $(element).qtip({
                    position: {
                        my: 'middle left', 
                        at: 'middle right'
                    },
                    show: {
                        event: 'focus'
                   ...
                   ...
                   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess I'm not fully understanding your implementation.  It seems pointless to use a form validation plugin and then bypass part of it with a custom `change` handler.  Since you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, why not just use its [built-in `email` rule](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/email)?

Otherwise, if you like your email function better, turn it into a custom rule using the [built-in `addMethod()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Validator/addMethod#namemethodmessage).

```
$.validator.addMethod("myCustomRule", function(value, element) { 
      return /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/.test(value); 
}, "Custom message for this rule");
```

It's implemented just like any other rule...

```
rules: {
   myfield: {
       myCustomRule: true
   }
}
```

---

As far as using qTip2 with jQuery Validate, I've done it like this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ 
        // any other options & rules,
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).filter(':not(.valid)').qtip({
                overwrite: false,
                content: error,
                show: {
                    event: false,
                    ready: true
                },
                hide: false
            }).qtip('option', 'content.text', error);
        },
        success: function (error) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                $('form').find('.valid').qtip('destroy');
            }, 1);
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO, jQuery Validate with qTip2:  http://jsfiddle.net/96AM4/**

---

However lately, I've been using Tooltipster instead because its integration with jQuery Validate is somewhat cleaner.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    // initialize Tooltipster on form input elements
    $('#myform input[type="text"]').tooltipster({ 
        trigger: 'custom', // default is 'hover' which is no good here
        onlyOne: false,    // allow multiple tips to be open at a time
        position: 'right'  // display the tips to the right of the element
    });

    // initialize jQuery Validate
    $('#myform').validate({
        // any other options & rules,
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            $(element).tooltipster('update', $(error).text());
            $(element).tooltipster('show');
        },
        success: function (label, element) {
            $(element).tooltipster('hide');
        }
    });

});
```

---

**Side-note**:

It's best not to leave a callbcak function empty like this:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
},
```

Use this instead if your intention is to suppress the default error messages:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    return false;
},
```

**DEMO, jQuery Validate with Tooltipster: http://jsfiddle.net/kyK4G/**

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply @Sparky. I am not using the email rule because anytime I use that rule and the rule evaluates to invalid, all text inputs after the invalid email evaluate to invalid after it, even BEFORE the user got a chance to fill it out. Tooltipster is interesting.... looking into it ;)

Comment: @MiGusta, the behavior you describe is not the normal default behavior of the plugin.  Can you set up a jsFiddle?

Comment: Your right, It isn't initially, but it is in my case because I placed the `qtip` event listener in the `highlight` call for the validation plugin... I'll try to post the jsFiddle later tonight or tomorrow. Thanks.

Comment: I set up a jsFiddle to demonstrate the problem I am having: http://jsfiddle.net/V7v6R/ , I appreciate any suggestions. Note when you type in an invalid e-mail is entered then all input fields that follow become 'invalid' before the user even has a chance to fill them out.

Comment: Also, I wasn't able to `addMethod()` successfully, can you possibly edit your code so the new method returns true if email is valid and false otherwise, and I can somehow use it in the `validate` call?

Comment: @MiGusta, are you sure you set up that jsFiddle properly?  I'm typing in all kinds of invalid stuff into the email field and absolutely nothing happens until I click the submit button.

Comment: Yes, type in something like `sdsdsdsd`.

Comment: @MiGusta, I have no idea what's happening when you tried to use `addMethod`... I merely copied and pasted _your_ regex into.  It's already supposed to return `true` when it passes.

Comment: @MiGusta, yes, I typed in `dgdsfgs` and nothing happens when I move around, nothing happens until I hit submit.

Comment: Right, I was able to create the new `method` but I don't really understand how to use that method in the validate() call so the validation fails if the e-mail is invalid.

Comment: Whats suppose to happen is after your type in some random text into the e-mail field the following input fields will have qtips saying the field is requried, before your even had a chance to fill them out, nothing like that happens? works perfectly on my end, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/V7v6R/3/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27779/discussion-between-mi-gusta-and-sparky)

Comment: @MiGusta, you declare it the same as any other rule within `.validate()`.  Like `required: true`, use `myCustomRule: true`.  Also, why is your `errorPlacement` callback function empty?  See my two tooltip examples above.